# Unlock table if browser is closed

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel

If someone wants to edit an entry in a table, I put a column "Locked" to true. If the user closed the browser / tab, how can I do it best so that the value is written by "Locked" back to false?

Is that possible with ajax? This can be seen when the user closes the browser / tab, then that ajax event fired?

Or is there a better and more reliable method? I work with laravel 4 und MSSQL.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to do this reliably. Also, I think you'll want to add some extra tags to your question.

Comment: Do you want to deal with the issue of concurrent edits or do you want to explicitly deny access to data you think is being edited by someone else? For the former you would use a version timestamp rather than a boolean, for the latter you cannot rely on an external notification so you would have to rely on a timeout value.

Answer (score 0):

This is very dangerous and highly unreliable, so if you need those rows unlocked, you better put a timeout on them too (a locked_at column), index the column and search for locked rows to unlock the timeouted ones. But...

You can hook on browser unload javascript event to help you with that:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    var s;
    event = event || window.event;
    if (requestsPending > 0) {
        s = "Your most recent changes are still being saved. " +
            "If you close the window now, they may not be saved.";
        event.returnValue = s;
        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tricky to do reliably, a couple of methods:

Use onbeforeunload as Antonio suggests, you could do an ajax request to release the lock?

Lock the record for x minutes on edit, then renew the lock via a polling ajax request just before the lock expires.